# order by slowing down query in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I am having  7M record. When I run the simple  query it's working fine but when I  use order by query slow down by 10 seconds

```
Select tblindustry.sectorName as name
    ,count(complainNumber) as sctrtotal
    ,count(if((complaintStatus='dispose off' || complaintStatus='closed'),0,null)) as sctrdspsd 
from tblcomplaints 
join tblindustry on tblindustry.sectorCode=tblcomplaints.sectorCode 
where (tblcomplaints.sectorCode!=44) 
    and date(complaintRegDate) >= '2019-01-01' 
group by tblindustry.sectorName 
order by sctrtotal desc  LIMIT 0,5
```

Without order by taking 0.8 seconds and with the order by taking 7 second

Comment: How many results would you get without the LIMIT? (Because that is how many MySQL has to sort with the ORDER BY first.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the table definitions you have (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and the result of `EXPLAIN ...` of your query. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Also, you probably don't need to use the DATE function; if your table is indexed on `complaintRegDate`, and that field is a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, MySQL should treat '2019-01-01'  as '2019-01-01 00:00:00'  automatically and be able to take advantage of the index. Even without the index, it is one less thing for MySQL to do to process every row.

Comment: please show EXPLAIN your query